# An hour of difference when substracting two long values

Tags: java, date, subtraction

I am trying to generate the total time taken by my program to complete its job to print at the end of the program's execution. Following are the lines of code, I am using, to achieve this.

```
long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis(), endTime;
//actual programming logic
 endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
System.out.println((new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss.SSS").format(new Date(endTime).getTime() - new Date(startTime).getTime())));
```

The result here is 01:00:00.582 in place of 00:00:00.582. While I can imagine, this may be a very commonly faced issue, I tried my best to search with best keywords for this issue on web but nothing caught my eyes yet. Could someone throw some light on this?

Any responses are much aprpeciated. Thank you.

Comment: Note that a duration/period is not a date.

Comment: It looks like you should be using `new Date(endTime - startTime)` even if you *do* continue with this approach...

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis but he should get a date based on 0:00 of Jan 1, 1970 (so, 0:00:00.582 of Jan 1, 1970)

Comment: There seems to be very little reason to go from `long` value to `Date` and back again. And I wonder if `format(long)` even compiles. Maybe use Joda time instead (until Java 8 arrives at least).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to produce what I am looking for. Here is the code for it, if someone needs it:

```
static String fn_Z_getTimeDifference(Long startTime, Long endTime)
{
    long processTime = endTime - startTime;
    long days = processTime / 86400000L;
    processTime -= days * 86400000L;
    long hours = processTime / 3600000L;
    processTime -= hours * 3600000L;
    long mins = processTime / 60000L;
    processTime -= mins * 60000L;
    long seconds = processTime / 1000L;
    processTime -= seconds * 1000L;
    long milliSeconds = processTime ;
    return (Long.toString(hours)+ ":" + Long.toString(mins) + ":" + Long.toString(seconds) + ":" + Long.toString(milliSeconds)).toString();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

When running code similar to your code:

```
long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis(), endTime;
try { Thread.sleep(582); } catch (InterruptedException ignored) {}
endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
System.out.println((new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss.SSS").format(
    new Date(endTime).getTime() - new Date(startTime).getTime())));
```

I get this output:

```
16:00:00.582
```

Showing the date reveals the time zone I'm in (UTC-8):

```
System.out.println((new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS").format(
    new Date(endTime).getTime() - new Date(startTime).getTime())));
```

Output:

```
1969-12-31 16:00:00.582
```

You are constructing a `Date` whose zero value is 00:00:00 January 1, 1970 UTC, but that is constructed in your own local time zone, which appears to have been one hour ahead of UTC on January 1, 1970.

Don't construct a `Date` using a time interval.

Answer (score 0):

You are formatting a number, because of wrapping and undwrapping the longs.

Try this

```
 ).format(new Date(endTime - startTime)));
```

or at the very least

```
 ").format(new Date(new Date(endTime).getTime() - new Date(startTime).getTime()))));
```